# How do I integrate javadoc into a website with other instructional information?

Tags: javadoc, code-documentation

Basically, we want to release an API on a CD as a JAR.  Along with the JAR, I was hoping we could have the javadoc, plus a readme, and maybe some examples all integrated together in a nice little website.  And I want the examples and readme not to get destroyed or unlinked every time I regenerate the javadoc.

I feel like there has to be something available off the shelf , but must I not be searching correctly.  Are there tools or best practices for this?

Thanks!